# App launched from npm works perfectly, but complied x64 app works incorrect

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-forge

I use the Electron-forge framework and try to make an audio player. When I launch my app from  `npm start` it works perfectly. But when I compile app using `npm run package` to x64 app and launch from its .exe file, the app works incorrectly. Window creates, but audio doesn't play.

> Error in console.log:"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

Paths to audio files are definitely correct, I wrote them to console too.

Edit: I found it is better to use Promise for tag `audio`, but the problem still persists. Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    prepare_song('D:' + '\\' + 'Downloads' + '\\' + 'audio_1.mp3');
    $("#button_play_pause").click(function () {
        console.log("click play");
        var playPromise = document.querySelector('audio').play();
        if (playPromise !== undefined) {
            playPromise.then(function () {
                console.log("play !");
                // triggered from npm start and music is playing
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("play error:" + error);
                // triggered from npm run package (x64 .exe app) Error: NotSupportedError: The element has no supported sources.
            });
        }
    });
});

function prepare_song(filepath) {
    console.log(" prepare: " + filepath);
    $("#audio").attr("src", filepath);
    let audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.load();
}
```

Comment: post the code please, community can't help you until and unless you provide what did you tried so far.